# Laravel hash id's and also use them?

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I have some buttons inside my foreach loop. Every button have his own `product_id`

for example:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductsController@bgs', 'method' => 'post']) !!}

         @foreach($products as $product)
          .... some non important data .... 
                <button value="{{ hash('sha256',$product->id) }}" name="id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Go!</button>
         @endforeach

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now in my controller I want to get some data from my database over the hashed id

Like:

```
$id = hash('sha256', Input::get('id'));
$product = Products::where('id', $id)->get();  // $id is hashed
```

and of course I'm getting nothing back as a result... So does anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would suggest saving the hash as an additional column in the database table, and looking the row up by that column rather than by id.

Comment: You want get anything because you hash on echo and on request you has already hashed value.

Comment: Why are you hashing the ID? Hashes are by design one-way, do you need to uniquely identify products or just prevent the user from tampering with other products than the one they're clicking on?

Comment: I don't want that the user changes the ID's in the HTML and get another items..

Comment: That's an authorization problem that you should be handling on the server-side anyway, e.g. in your "update"/"store" methods pull the ID of the currently logged-in user and then verify that they're actually allowed to do whatever it is that they're trying to do. Same for "show"/"index" methods - you should be querying only those models which belong to the user. As for the user changing the product ID and then submitting the form - as long as the list only contains "their" data, ultimately they're screwing themselves over if they mess with the HTML, I wouldn't worry about that too much.

Comment: hey that idea sounds good. thanks! :)